# AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'create_widgets'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little problem with my code. I have to make a sumator but I have an error and I don't know where I have a mistake. It says

```
"AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'create_widgets'.
```

I would be grateful if you help me fix the problem!

[image: here is the error]

````
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

#create the app
app = Application()
app.master.frame()
app.master.title("Sumator")
app.master.minsize(width=100, height=50)

#start the program
app.mainloop()

def create_widgets(self):
    #create widgets
    self.firstNumberEntry = tk.Entry()
    self.plusSign = tk.Label(text = "+")
    self.secondNumberEntry = tk.Entry()
    self.equalSign = tk.Label(text = "=")
    self.resultLabel = tk.Label(text = "Result...", bg = "green", fg = "white")
    self.calculateButton = tk.Button(text = "Calculate", command = self.calculate)

    #place widgets
    self.firstNumberEntry.pack(side = "left")
    self.plusSign.pack(side = "left")
    self.secondNumberEntry.pack(side = "left")
    self.equalSign.pack(side = "left")
    self.resultLabel.pack(side = "left")
    self.calculateButton.pack(side = "left")

def calculate(self):
    try:
        first_value = float(self.firstNumberEntry.get())
        second_value = float(self.secondNumberEntry.get())
        result = first_value + second_value
        self.resultLabel.config(text = str(result), bg = "green", fg = "white")

    except ValueError:
        self.resultLabel.config(text="No number/s", bg="red", fg="black")```
````

Comment: Methods `create_widgets` and `calculate` are in the class, theyr should be indented like the `__init__` and the main code should after that, outside the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods `create_widgets` and `calculate` are not in your class actually, they should be indented like the `__init__` , like this

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        #...

    def calculate(self):
        #...

#create the app
app = Application()
app.master.frame()
app.master.title("Sumator")
app.master.minsize(width=100, height=50)

#start the program
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the `calculate(self)` function and the `create_widgets(self)` function into your `Application` class. This way, python knows they are part of the class.

I also made several improvements to your program, such as making it look nicer.

Here is the final code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
    #create widgets
        self.firstNumberEntry = tk.Entry(bd = 0)
        self.plusSign = tk.Label(text = "+")
        self.secondNumberEntry = tk.Entry(bd = 0)
        self.equalSign = tk.Label(text = "=")
        self.resultLabel = tk.Label(text = "Result...", bg = "green", fg = "white")
        self.calculateButton = tk.Button(text = "Calculate", command = self.calculate, bd = 0, relief = "flat")
        self.calculateButton.config(activebackground = self.calculateButton.master.cget("bg"))

        #place widgets
        self.firstNumberEntry.pack(side = "left")
        self.plusSign.pack(side = "left")
        self.secondNumberEntry.pack(side = "left")
        self.equalSign.pack(side = "left")
        self.resultLabel.pack(side = "left")
        self.calculateButton.pack(side = "left")

    def calculate(self):
            try:
                first_value = float(self.firstNumberEntry.get())
                second_value = float(self.secondNumberEntry.get())
                result = first_value + second_value
                self.resultLabel.config(text = str(result), bg = "green", fg = "white")

            except ValueError:
                self.resultLabel.config(text="No number/s", bg="red", fg="black")

#create the app
app = Application()
app.master.frame()
app.master.title("Sumator")
app.master.minsize(width=100, height=50)

#start the program
app.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps you!